# Matching strict whole word using flex, lex, leex

Tags: regex, erlang, leex

I've just started using leex and yecc to do the lexer/parser stuff for a really simple control shell.

My lexer definition :

```
Definitions.

COMMAND =  STATUS|START|RELOAD|EXIT|STOP|RESTART
NAME       = [a-z_][a-z_0-9]*
WHITESPACE = [\s\t\n\r]

Rules.

{COMMAND}     : {token, {command,  TokenLine, list_to_atom(TokenChars)}}.
{NAME}        : {token, {name, TokenLine, TokenChars}}.
{WHITESPACE}+ : skip_token.

Erlang code.
```

Nothing much really. Simple case are working fine:

```
iex(0)> :lexer.string('START')
{:ok, [{:command, 1, :START}], 1}
iex(1)> :lexer.string('START STOP')
{:ok, [{:command, 1, :START}, {:command, 1, :STOP}], 1}
iex(2)> :lexer.string('START foobar')
{:ok, [{:command, 1, :START}, {:name, 1, 'foobar'}], 1}
```

But these have been bothering me:

```
iex(3)> :lexer.string('STARTo')
{:ok, [{:command, 1, :START}, {:name, 1, 'o'}], 1}
```

Instead i want something like:

```
iex(3)> :lexer.string('STARTo')
{:ok, [{:illegal, 'STARTo'}], 1}
```

But i can't figure how to make match at word boundary using these kind of tools (which use a *slim* impl. for regex btw)

Ps: In case, I know that this isn't the *right* way to do it, but just wanting to know if possible and how

**EDIT**
Removing lex and flex tag since this seems to be limitation from leex and not from these *tools

Comment: How about changing the definition of a command to be `START(\s|$)`? I included an online example, but I don't know if `leex` supports this kind of regex. https://regex101.com/r/OWpRPL/1

Comment: Guess it could have work like this `COMMAND =  (\s|^)(STATUS|START|RELOAD|EXIT|STOP|RESTART)(\s|$)` but anchoring though documented is not implemented :(

Comment: I used `[\s\r\n\t]` as a boundary here:

https://github.com/derek121/mrwhite/blob/master/priv/from_text_lexer.xrl
from
https://github.com/derek121/mrwhite